# Middleware to check existence of domain in Django

Tags: django

I have a single application which manages and delivers several sites. I does this by determining which domain to serve from the URL:

http://myapplication.com/site_1/
or
http://myapplication.com/site_2/

Each site obviously has it's own pages, so might end up with a url like this:

http://myapplication.com/site_1/contact_us/

What I'd like to do is create some middleware which, when a url such as the two above (http://myapplication.com/somedomainhere) it will check the existence of that particular domain in a database (which I have already created) and, if it exists, continue to the index view. If the domain doesn't exist, I want to divert to a 404 page.

Is this something which is relatively simple to do with middleware and if so, does anyone have any examples of how I might go about accomplishing this?

I am aware of the Sites framework which comes with Django, but I will be using the above to create something slightly different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    class MyMiddleware():
    def process_request(self, request):
        app_name = request.path.split('/')[0]

        try:
            app = Apps.objects.get(name=app_name)
        except DoesNotExist:
            return

        request.urlconf = app.urlconf
        return
```

The include your middleware in your `settings.py` with all the rest.

This assumes that your app model includes a property that knows about the urlconf for that app.  Just point the request at that urlconf, and Django takes care of the rest.

For reference, see the documentation on [middleware](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/http/middleware/#topics-http-middleware), [request processing](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request) and setting the [urlconfs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/http/urls/#example).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks very much. This is round about what I want, but I'm a little stumped by the app.urlconf part, what exactly should I be returning from within my model?

Comment: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.urlconf explains how the request.urlconf is used.  Hope that helps.